# Need help to fix my create multi-dimensional array using Object code

Tags: php, arrays, loops

I have Json data coming in following format:

```
    stdClass Object
(
    [sources] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 147
                    [name] => CatsWhoCode.com
                    [segments] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [id] => 104
                                    [name] => Default
                                    [style] => EDUCATIONAL
                                    [targetAudience] => KNOWLEDGEABLE
                                    [isPrimary] => 1
                                )

                        )

                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 181
                    [name] => Inspire Trends - Your Daily Dose of Design and Development Resources
                    [segments] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [id] => 146
                                    [name] => Inspire Trends
                                    [style] => TECHNICAL
                                    [targetAudience] => KNOWLEDGEABLE
                                    [isPrimary] => 1
                                )

                            [1] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [id] => 147
                                    [name] => Inspire Trends
                                    [style] => EDUCATIONAL
                                    [targetAudience] => KNOWLEDGEABLE
                                    [isPrimary] => 0
                                )

                        )

                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [id] => 182
                    [name] => Designmodo
                    [segments] => Array
                        (
                            [0] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [id] => 148
                                    [name] => Design Modo
                                    [style] => INFORMAL
                                    [targetAudience] => KNOWLEDGEABLE
                                    [isPrimary] => 1
                                )

                            [1] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [id] => 149
                                    [name] => Design Modo
                                    [style] => INFORMATIVE
                                    [targetAudience] => GENERAL
                                    [isPrimary] => 0
                                )

                        )

                )

        )

    [status] => 10
)
```

and I am trying to filter it and create (multi-dimensional) array that should look like following:

```
Array
(
    [CatsWhoCode.com] => Array
        (
                    [104] => [PRI] Default
        )

    [Inspire Trends - Your Daily Dose of Design and Development Resources] => Array
        (
                    [146] => [PRI] Inspire Trends
                    [147] =>  Inspire Trends
        )

    [Designmodo] => Array
        (
                    [148] => [PRI] Design Modo
                    [149] =>  Design Modo

        )

)
```

but from my code, I am ending up getting following result:

```
Array
(
    [CatsWhoCode.com] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [104] => [PRI] Default
                )

        )

    [Inspire Trends - Your Daily Dose of Design and Development Resources] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [146] => [PRI] Inspire Trends
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [147] =>  Inspire Trends
                )

        )

    [Designmodo] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [148] => [PRI] Design Modo
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [149] =>  Design Modo
                )

        )

)
```

Here is my code, I cannot figure out how to fix this.

```
function ar_audienceList($AR){
        $audienceList = $AR->getAudienceList();

            foreach ($audienceList->sources AS $key => $source){
            foreach($source->segments AS $v){
                                            if ($v->isPrimary == 1)$pri = "[PRI]";                
                    $options[$source->name][] = array($v->id => $pri." ".$v->name,);
                    $pri = ''; // reset primary
                }
            }

    return $options;


}
```

Thanks

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/21097885/3) is sort of what I really had in mind (though it's still not a very good title because it doesn't describe your problem).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rather than indexing each element in `$options[$source->name]` to the next available index (`[]`), you want to index it to the id of the `$source->segments` (`[$v->id]`).

```
function ar_audienceList($AR)
{
    $audienceList = $AR->getAudienceList();
    foreach ($audienceList->sources as $key => $source)
    {
        foreach($source->segments AS $v)
        {
            if ($v->isPrimary == 1)
            {
                $pri = "[PRI]";
            }        
            $options[$source->name][$v->id] = $pri." ".$v->name; // Change is here
            $pri = ''; // reset primary
        }
    }
    return $options;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much this worked. I tried this before but it did not really work.     '$options[$source->name][$v->id] = array($pri." ".$v->name);  Thank you. Thanks or the explanation too.